# Complexity of generating all pairs of words in a line for every line in a file

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

So I have a text file which contains lines of text. I'm reading the file line by line and for each line I'm generating all possible 2-pairs of each word where order doesn't matter. For example, given the line `'How are you'` what I'm generating is `['how are' ,'how you' , 'are you']`. My question is what would be the time complexity for this? I know it takes `O(n)` to read every word in a file and it takes `O(n^2)` to generate the pairs, so would it be `O(n^3)` since for every line I'm doing `O(n^2)` amount of work?

Comment: `...generate all permutations...`. I don't see you generating any permutations you are just generating pairs. The title is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have `n` lines and the maximum length ( the number of words) is `k`. Then your complexity would be `O(n*k^2)`. It is important to distinguish the number of lines and length of a line since, in general, the files tend to have many lines and length of the lines is usually small.

However, suppose that your long lines are rare. If you average length is `k'` then you might think that your amortized run-time is `O(n*k'^2)`. But consider the case when your first line has length `n*k'` and the rest have length `0`. Then your amortized run-time is `O(n^2*k'^2)` - not what you expected. You can indeed prove that `O(n^2*k'^2)` is the bound of the amortized run-time. Note that in the above-mentioned degenerate case  `O(n^2*k'^2)` is better bound than `O(n*k^2)` since `n*k^2` is simply equal to `n*(n*k')^2 = n^3k'^2`. So as long as `n^2*k'^2 <= n*k^2`, that is `k'<= k/sqrt(n)` ( meaning the average length is less than the max length divided by sqrt(n)) then the bound `O(n^2*k'^2)` is better than the bound `O(n*k^2)`.

Comment: ahhh I see. What if you do not know the maximum number of words in a line and if every line has a varying amount of words? Is it okay to generalize the length of each line to be k? Or, would we consider the average length of each line and have `O(n avg(k))`

Comment: @raysmith that was just what I was going to write